# array_splice with multidimensional arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-splice

Okay so I'm fairly new to PHP and I am currently experimenting with arrays. As an example, lets assume this is my array:

```
    $t1 = array (
  "basicInfo" => array (
   "The Sineps",
   "December 25, 2010",
   "lemonpole_1g"
  ),
  "overallRecord" => array (
   "23",
   "12",
   "19",
   ""
  )
);
```

From what I could gather, I found out that the function **array_splice** allows me to point to a specific index in the array and add/remove data. From all of the examples that I've seen using this function...only numeric arrays were used. Now my question is how would I point to **["overallRecord"][3]**(which is empty) for example, and update that field?

For further understanding that empty field is for "total points":

```
$wins = $t1["overallRecord"][0] * 3;
$loss = $t1["overallRecord"][1];
$draw = $t1["overallRecord"][2];
$total = $wins + $draw;
```

So to sum it all up, I'd like to add the variable **$total** to **["overallRecord"][3]**. It doesn't necessarily have to be with **array_splice**, however, if you come up with a different method to achieve this try and keep it simple or add comments please :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, simply do

```
$t1["overallRecord"][3] = $total;
```

Comment: Oh it is really that simple? And the field will be updated dynamically whenever I change the other keys?

Comment: @Henrik, yes it's really that simple (unless there's something different between your actual array and the example you gave).

Comment: oh tried it out and it worked just fine; and here i was thinking something extremely complicated was needed to achieve this, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$t1["overallRecord"][3] = $total;
```